# How to preserve reference invariants in F#?

Tags: f#

Given I have the following type

```ml
type Die<'face> = { Faces: 'face list; CurrentFace: 'face; }
```

how could I preserve the invariant that the `CurrentFace` is one of the values in `Faces`?

### Approach: By Reference

I was thinking of using a reference to the `Faces` list

```ml
type Die<'face> = { Faces: 'face list; CurrentFaceIndex: int; }
```

or

```ml
type DieFaceId = Value of Guid
type DieFace<'value> = { Id: DieFaceId; Value: 'value; }
type Die<'faceValue> = { Faces: DieFace<'faceValue> list; CurrentFaceId: DieFaceId; }
```

however I could not find a way of preserving the invariant "the face reference must match a face included in the Faces list".

Comment: Are you trying to get the compiler to enforce this invariant?

Comment: No, I do not need the compiler to enforce this invariant. However I am looking for a design that neatly enforces this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```ml
type Die<'face> =
    private {
        _CurrentFace: 'face
        _OtherFaces: 'face list
    }
    member die.CurrentFace = die._CurrentFace
    member die.Faces = die._CurrentFace :: die._OtherFaces
```

The public interface is the same as before, but the implementation that enforces the invariant is now hidden, so you'll also need a way for clients to create dice:

```ml
module Die =

    let create = function
        | face :: otherFaces ->
            {
                _CurrentFace = face
                _OtherFaces = otherFaces
            }
        | _ -> failwith "Empty die"
```

And you can change the current face of a die like this:

```ml
    let setCurrentFace face (die : Die<_>) =
        let iFace = List.findIndex ((=) face) die.Faces
        {
            _CurrentFace = die.Faces[iFace]
            _OtherFaces = die.Faces |> List.removeAt iFace
        }
```

You might want to consider using `Set<_>` instead of `List<_>` to hold your faces, though.

Example usage:

```ml
let die = Die.create [1..6]
printfn "%A" die
let die' = Die.setCurrentFace 6 die
printfn "%A" die'
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I remember seeing a similar pattern for ensuring a never-empty list but did not consider using that here. Thank you for your insight 